# How to echo special characters like » on using code page 437?

Tags: batch-file, echo

I am currently working on a batch file and using the code page 437. I want the batch to echo the *right pointing double angle quotation mark*, but can't figure out for the life of me how or find what the equivalent would be.

Comment: You will need to save the batch script in the `unicode` encoding type. By default, text documents in most cases are saved as `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia article about [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) lists all characters this code page defines with their code values.

The character [right-pointing double angle quotation mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet) `»` has Unicode code value U+00BB. It is available also in code page 437 with decimal code value 175 (hexadecimal AF).

So best is to use a text editor for writing this batch file which supports editing the file with [OEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_equipment_manufacturer) code page 437.

But in case of using Windows Notepad not supporting editing text files with any code page, you have to use *ANSI* [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) and insert the [macron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron_(diacritic)) character `¯` into the batch file which has the decimal code value 175 (hex. AF) in code page [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1252) which is the default system *ANSI* code page on not using Unicode in countries which have code page 437 as system OEM code page.

*ANSI* is here a common acronym for **one byte per character** encoding. The code pages `Windows-1252` and `437` are not really specified by the [American National Standards Institute (ANSI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_National_Standards_Institute).